Dynamically change padding in Vue js 3
Hello I want to change padding based on my selected locale, since div width is changing.
  <div
    class="input-group modal-check-show show-modal"
    :style="paddingLeft"
  >
  . . .
  </div>

const EnPaddingLeft = ref('padding-left: 27%;')
const DePaddingLeft = ref('padding-left: 28%;')
const SrPaddingLeft = ref('padding-right: 33% !important;')

const setPaddingLeft = computed(() => {
  let padding
  if (Tr.currentLocale === 'en') {
    padding = EnPaddingLeft
  } else if (Tr.currentLocale === 'de') {
    padding = DePaddingLeft
  } else if (Tr.currentLocale === 'sr') {
    padding = SrPaddingLeft
  } else {
    padding = EnPaddingLeft
  }
  return padding
})
const paddingLeft = setPaddingLeft


When I change computed to method it shows up at div tag, but it doesn't change padding when I change locale.

is Tr.currentLocale reactive?

Yes it is, everything changes with locale(I mean all the text).

why are EnPaddingLeft etc refs? if they need to be, then surely you need padding = EnPaddingLeft.value etc?

I have added ref so I can access them in method and then I forgot to move it.
Probably is that .value(I'm new to it).

what is method? are you using composition API in a <script setup>?

Function = method, yes I'm using <script setup>.

in <script setup> You can access any variables, they don't need to be ref - but if they are ref then you access the value using .value

does your code work if you remove ref?

and why do you have const setPaddingLeft = computed(() => { then const paddingLeft = setPaddingLeft? just do const paddingLeft = computed(() => {

It works, Thank you very much

Can you answer it so I can finish the thread?

For paddingLeft = setPaddingLeft , I have tried everything since i couldn't solve it

The primary issue in the provided code is that the computed property setPaddingLeft should be used as a reactive reference in Vue 3. Instead of directly assigning setPaddingLeft to paddingLeft.
In your code, just remove setPaddingLeft and directly return the reactive reference paddingLeft should be fine.
const paddingLeft = computed(() => {
  let padding
  if (Tr.currentLocale === 'en') {
    padding = EnPaddingLeft
  } else if (Tr.currentLocale === 'de') {
    padding = DePaddingLeft
  } else if (Tr.currentLocale === 'sr') {
    padding = SrPaddingLeft
  } else {
    padding = EnPaddingLeft
  }
  return padding
})

// Below assignment is not needed, and will cause issue since paddingLeft is not reactive.
// const paddingLeft = setPaddingLeft

